# Is every basis with one vector an orthogonal basis?

Tags: linear-algebra

In mathematics, particularly linear algebra, an orthogonal basis for an inner product space V is a basis for V whose vectors are mutually orthogonal.

What if we have a basis with only one vector?
Is this an orthogonal basis automatically?

Comment: Trivially yes..

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is vacuously an orthogonal basis.